# How to solve webview flutter platform error on build

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm updating a flutter app that used `flutter_webview_plugin` to `webview_flutter`. I'm also using `webview_flutter_platform_interface` plugin.
I've changed the object of the `FlutterWebviewPlugin` to `WebViewController`.

but when I'm trying to run build I get the following error:

> "a platform implementation for webview_flutter has not been set. please ensure that an implementation of webviewplatform has been set to webviewplatform.instance".

Where and how should I implement this instance?

I've changed the object of the `FlutterWebviewPlugin` to `WebViewController`.

this is the main part of pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.2.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  http: ^0.13.5 
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.4 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  provider: ^6.0.5
  url_launcher: ^6.1.9
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
  esys_flutter_share:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/cihadturhan/esys-flutter-share.git
      ref: nullsafety+embedding-2
  webview_flutter_platform_interface: ^2.0.1
```

this is webview_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.dart';
import 'package:local_story/screens/timelines_screen.dart';

class WebViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;

  WebViewScreen({this.url});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: TimelinesScreen().getWebviewPlatform()),
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is timeline_screen.dart:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
// #docregion platform_imports
// Import for Android features.
import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';
// Import for iOS features.
import 'package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.dart';
// #enddocregion platform_imports
import 'package:local_story/components/app_drawer.dart';
import 'package:local_story/components/loading.dart';
import 'package:local_story/constants/color_constants.dart';
import 'package:local_story/icons/custom_icons.dart';
import 'package:local_story/screens/webview_screen.dart';
import 'package:local_story/services/local_story_api_service.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter_platform_interface/webview_flutter_platform_interface.dart';

class TimelinesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  _TimelinesScreenState createState() => _TimelinesScreenState();
  WebViewController getWebviewPlatform() =>
      _TimelinesScreenState().getWebviewPlatform();
}

class _TimelinesScreenState extends State<TimelinesScreen> {
  var stageDomain = 'https://teststage.localtimeline.com/index.php?lang=he';
  var hebrewLang = true;
  var debugDomain = false;
  var debugCount = 0;
  var _username = '';
  var _email = '';
  var _password = '';
  var _originalList = List(); // Holds unfiltered list fetched from the api
  var _originalEngList =
      List(); // Holds unfiltered English list fetched from the api
  var _originalEngListTitles =
      List(); // Holds unfiltered English titles list fetched from the api
  var _uiList = List(); // Holds filtered results when using the search bar
  var _uiEngList =
      List(); // Holds filtered English results when using the search bar
  var _uiEngListTitles = List(); // Holds filtered English titles
  var _searchFieldController = TextEditingController();
  var _scrollController =
      ScrollController(); // Used to scroll down the list view when clicking the floating button
  var _showFloatingButton = false;
  var _firstPress =
      true; // used to prevent opening more than one instance of the save webview

  Future<dynamic>
      _timelines; // Used to get timelines from api and initialize the future builder in the build method

  Future<dynamic> getTimelines() async {
    var timelines;
    var emptyList = true;
    // Fetch timelines from api
    timelines = await LocalStoryAPIService().getTimelines();

    // If no timelines fetched, user is not connected to internet...
    if (timelines == null) return 0;

    // initialize the orriginal list and ui list
    _originalList.addAll(timelines);
    for (var i = 0; i < _originalList.length; i++) {
      if (_originalList[i]['translations'] != null) {
        if (_originalList[i]['translations']['en'] != null) {
          if (_originalList[i]['translations']['en']['title'] != null) {
            //print("Position $i : ${_originalList[i]['title']} ");
            emptyList = false;
            _originalEngList.add(_originalList[i]);
            _uiEngList.add(_originalList[i]);
            _originalEngListTitles
                .add(_originalList[i]['translations']['en']['title']);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // if english list is empty take the first from hebrew
    if (emptyList) {
      //print("Position 000 : ${_originalList[0]['title']} ");
      _originalEngList.add(_originalList[0]);
      _uiEngList.add(_originalList[0]);
      _originalEngListTitles.add(_originalList[0]['title']);
    }
    _uiEngListTitles.addAll(_originalEngListTitles);
    _uiList.addAll(timelines);
    setState(() {
      _showFloatingButton = true;
    });

    // return the timelines because the FutureBuilder in build(context) needs to know whether
    // timeilnes were found.
    return timelines;
  }

  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    // Create a temp list made of the original list
    // in order to loop through and search for results
    List<dynamic> tempSearchList = new List<dynamic>();
    List<dynamic> tempSearchEngList = new List<dynamic>();
    List<dynamic> tempSearchEngListTitle = new List<dynamic>();
    tempSearchList.addAll(_originalList);
    tempSearchEngList.addAll(_originalEngList);
    tempSearchEngListTitle.addAll(_originalEngListTitles);

    // check if we didn't get an empty query
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      // Set the ui list with filtered results
      setState(() {
        _uiList.clear();
        _uiList.addAll(
            tempSearchList.where((item) => item['title'].contains(query)));
        _uiEngList.clear();
        _uiEngListTitles.clear();
        for (var i = 0; i < tempSearchEngListTitle.length; i++) {
          if (tempSearchEngListTitle[i].contains(query)) {
            _uiEngList.add(tempSearchEngList[i]);
            _uiEngListTitles.add(tempSearchEngListTitle[i]);
          }
        }
//        _uiEngList.addAll(
//            tempSearchEngList.where((item) => item['title'].contains(query)));
//        _uiList.addAll(tempSearchList
//            .where((item) => item['translations']['en'].isNotEmpty));
      });
      // if we did, return the origin list
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _uiList.clear();
        _uiList.addAll(_originalList);
        _uiEngList.clear();
        _uiEngList.addAll(_originalEngList);
        _uiEngListTitles.clear();
        _uiEngListTitles.addAll(_originalEngListTitles);
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> goToDomain(String timelineDomain) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // Check if there is alredy a token in the device's memory
    // If there is, we can use this to go to a timeline with
    // a logged in user
    if (preferences.getString('name') != null) {
      _username = preferences.getString('name');
      _email = preferences.getString('email');
      _password = preferences.getString('password');
    }

    var url = '';

    // Feature that will always take the user to the last domain when open app
    await preferences.setString('domain', timelineDomain);

    // if a user is logged in and picked a timeline last time, go to that timeline
    if (_username != '') {
      dynamic res = await LocalStoryAPIService()
          .loginUser(timelineDomain, _username, _email, _password);

      if (res['status']['code'] == 200) {
        // Important if we cancel 'always last domain' feature
        await preferences.setString('domain', timelineDomain);
        url = timelineDomain + '&userAuthToken=${res['data']['userAuthToken']}';
      } else {
        url = timelineDomain;
      }
    } else {
      url = timelineDomain;
    }

    if (_firstPress == true) {
      setState(() {
        _firstPress = false;
      });
      setUpListener();
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => WebViewScreen(
            url: url,
          ),
        ),
      ).whenComplete(() {
        setState(() {
          _firstPress = true;
        });
      });
      return;
    }
  }

  String getDomain(int index) {
    var result = stageDomain;
    var lang = hebrewLang ? '&lang=he' : '&lang=en';
    if (!debugDomain) {
      result =
          hebrewLang ? _uiList[index]['domain'] : _uiEngList[index]['domain'];
    }

    result = result + lang;
    //print('domain: ' + result);
    return result;
  }

  // whatsapp fix start1
  // Instance of WebView plugin
  //var flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  var flutterWebviewPlugin = WebViewController(); // = new Webv;

  WebViewController getWebviewPlatform() {
    return flutterWebviewPlugin;
  }
//  // On destroy stream
//  StreamSubscription _onDestroy;

  // On urlChanged stream
  StreamSubscription<String> _onUrlChanged;

//  // On urlChanged stream
//  StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onStateChanged;
//  StreamSubscription<WebViewHttpError> _onHttpError;
//  StreamSubscription<double> _onScrollYChanged;
//  StreamSubscription<double> _onScrollXChanged;
//  final _urlCtrl = new TextEditingController(text: selectedUrl);
//  final _codeCtrl =
//      new TextEditingController(text: 'window.navigator.userAgent');
//  final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
//  final _history = [];

  // whatsapp fix end1

  // late final WebViewController controller;

  WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    retriveLenguage();
    goBackToTimeline();
    _timelines = getTimelines();
    super.initState();

    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'),
      );
  }

  // whatsapp fix start2

  void setUpListener() {
    //print('\nsetUpListener\n');
    // flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
    flutterWebviewPlugin = WebViewController(); // = new WebViewPlatform();

    if (_onUrlChanged != null) {
      _onUrlChanged.cancel();
      //print('\n_onUrlChanged != null canceled');
    } else {
      //print('\n_onUrlChanged == null');
    }
    _onUrlChanged =
        // flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
        flutterWebviewPlugin.setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
            onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
      /*if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },*/
      String url = request.url;
      //print('\n_onUrlChanged');

      var linkToShare = 'NoLink';
      //print("navigating to...$url");

      // If site knows the agent and "signal" the app to share
      if (url.startsWith("localtimeline://share")) {
        //print('startsWith localtimeline://share\n');
        var uri = Uri.parse('$url');
        if (uri.queryParameters.containsKey('text')) {
          linkToShare = uri.queryParameters['text'];
//          print('the text to send is $linkToShare');
        }
      }

      // If site try to share to whatsapp ( whatsapp://send?text=https://hamadia.localtimeline.com/?lang=he&timeline=1&whatsapp=1 )
      if (url.startsWith("whatsapp")) {
        //print('startsWith whatsapp\n');
        // await flutterWebviewPlugin.stopLoading();
        // await flutterWebviewPlugin.goBack();
//        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
//          await launch(url);
//          return;
//        }
        //print("couldn't launch $url\n");
        var uri = Uri.parse('$url');
//        uri.queryParameters.forEach((k, v) {
//          print('key: $k - value: $v');
//        });
        if (uri.queryParameters.containsKey('text')) {
          linkToShare = uri.queryParameters['text'];
//          print('the text to send is $linkToShare');
        }

        //print('startsWith\n');
      }

      // If site try to share to facebook
      // iOS: catch (1) https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLTOSHARE
      // (2) https://m.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLTOSHARE
      // (3) https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxx&signed_next=1&next=https://m.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLTOSHARE and then some more
      // android catch (3) only

      if (url.startsWith("https://www.facebook.com") ||
          url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com")) {
        //print('startsWith facebook yes\n');
        var uri = Uri.parse('$url');

        if (uri.queryParameters.containsKey('u')) {
          //print('containsKey u1\n');
          linkToShare = uri.queryParameters['u'];
        } else if (uri.queryParameters.containsKey('next')) {
          //print('containsKey next\n');
          var nextlinkToShare = uri.queryParameters['next'];
          //print('nextlinkToShare: $nextlinkToShare\n');
          var nexturi = Uri.parse('$nextlinkToShare');

          if (nexturi.queryParameters.containsKey('u')) {
            //print('containsKey u\n');
            linkToShare = nexturi.queryParameters['u'];
            //print('the text to send is $linkToShare');
          }
        }
      }

      // Only if you have a link to share, Navigate back and try to share it on device
      if (linkToShare != 'NoLink') {
        // await flutterWebviewPlugin.stopLoading();
        // await flutterWebviewPlugin.goBack();

        try {
          Share.text('Link from Local timeline', linkToShare, 'text/plain');
        } catch (e) {
          print('error: $e');
        }
      }
    })) as StreamSubscription<String>;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Every listener should be canceled, the same should be done with this stream.
    //print('\ndispose\n');
    if (_onUrlChanged != null) {
      _onUrlChanged.cancel();
      //print('\n_onUrlChanged != null canceled');
    }
    // flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
  // whatsapp fix end2

  Future<void> switchLang() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    hebrewLang = !hebrewLang;
    await preferences.setString('lang', hebrewLang ? 'he' : 'en');
  }

  Future<void> retriveLenguage() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // Check if the device storage saved a Lenguage
    String langStr = preferences.getString('lang');

    // If there was a domain, automatically navigate to it
    if (langStr != null && langStr.isNotEmpty) {
      hebrewLang = (langStr == 'he');
    } else {
      await preferences.setString('lang', 'he');
    }
  }

  Future<void> goBackToTimeline() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // Check if the device storage saved a domain
    // when the app previously opened
    String domain = preferences.getString('domain');

    // If there was a domain, automatically navigate to it
    if (domain != null && domain.isNotEmpty) {
      goToDomain(domain);

      // Navigator.push(
      //   context,
      //   MaterialPageRoute(
      //     builder: (context) => WillPopScope(
      //       child: WebViewScreen(
      //         url: domain,
      //       ),
      //       onWillPop: () async {
      //         // When the user clicks on back, remove
      //         // the saved domain from the device's memory
      //         await preferences.setString('domain', '');
      //         return true;
      //       },
      //     ),
      //   ),
      // );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:
            Text(hebrewLang ? 'רשימת הסיפורים המקומיים' : 'Our Local Stories'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logo-symbol@2x.png',
              height: 36,
              width: 36,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      /*body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),*/
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _timelines,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data == 0)
              return Center(
                child: Text(hebrewLang ? 'אין חיבור לרשת...' : '...No network'),
              );
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // SEARCH ********************************************************************************************
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 16),
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            filterSearchResults(value);
                          },
                          controller: _searchFieldController,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12, right: 14),
                            hintText: hebrewLang ? "חיפוש" : "Search",
                            suffixIcon: _searchFieldController.text.length == 0
                                ? Icon(Icons.search)
                                : IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.close,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // clear the  text field and refresh to the whole list
                                      _searchFieldController.text = '';
                                      filterSearchResults('');
                                    },
                                  ),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(5),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.language,
                          color:
                              hebrewLang ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.blue[700],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            switchLang();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(hebrewLang ? 'Eng' : 'Heb'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  // LISTVIEW ********************************************************************************************
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: hebrewLang ? _uiList.length : _uiEngList.length,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 7, bottom: 7, right: 30, left: 17.25),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                                bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffdfe0df)))),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            '${hebrewLang ? _uiList[index]['title'] : _uiEngListTitles[index]}',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                          ),
                          trailing: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                          onTap: () async => await goToDomain(getDomain(index)),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            // Loading ********************************************************************************************
            return Loading();
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: _showFloatingButton,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
          height: 27,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            elevation: 0,
            onPressed: () {
              debugCount = debugCount + 1;
              if (debugCount > 14) {
                debugCount = 0;
                setState(() {
                  debugDomain = !debugDomain;
                });
              }
              //print(debugDomain);
              _scrollController.animateTo(
                _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                curve: Curves.easeOut,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              );
            },
            mini: true,
            backgroundColor: debugDomain ? Colors.black38 : kPrimaryColor,
            child: Icon(
              CustomIcons.down_btn,
              size: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code.

Comment: Please don't paste your code in comment edit you question and paste it over there.

Comment: @SagarAcharya added the code to the question

Comment: Can you just also post the TimelinesScreen class which has getWebviewPlatform method